# Clear EditText from ViewModel when Submit is clicked via Binding

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, data-binding

I have trying to clear the EditText from the ViewModel when the **Comment** is clicked. I have binded by View to the ViewModel along with the Comment button. Is there a way to clear the EditText when the comment button is clicked from the View without having to create an OnClick listener in the actual activity?

Here is the View code.

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/Comment_button"
   android:onClick="@{() -> ViewModel.newComment()}"
   android:text="Comment"/>

<EditText
   android:id="@+id/Comment_textbox"
   android:text="@={ViewModel.Comment}" />
```

Here is the ViewModel that it is accessing.

```
var Comment : String? = null

fun newComment()
    {
        //Sends data to repostitory.
    }
```

Is there some code I could put that would clear the EditText without having to make an onclick listener in the Activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a simple `String` property, you can create an `ObservableField<String>`

Do the following changes,

```
var Comment  =  ObservableField<String>()
```

And then in your bound method

```
fun newComment()
    {
        Comment.set("")
    }
```

As a result whenever your `Comment` property changes, it will be immediately reflected on your `UI`.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Comment_textbox.setText(""); //
```

Comment: This would work in the View which is not what I asked. Regardless, I upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use LiveData and MutableLiveData.

In your example make following:
In your ViewModel declare

```
private val _comment = MutableLiveData<String?> = null
val comment: LiveData<String?>?
```

Then in your newComment() function from viewModel after you add new comment
just clear value of _comment:

```
_comment.value = null
```

That's it. After this your edit text would be automatically cleared.
Also to update your comment value in viewmodel when you type  comment in EditText add atribiute to EditText:

```
android:afterTextChanged="@{viewmodel::setComment}"
```

and in viewmodel define function :

```
 fun setComment(s:Editable) {
    _comment.value = s.toString()
}
```

That's it.